# How to use sample data in Composable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

In XML we use sample name, date etc. by using attributes like **@tools:sample/first_names**.
Is there any way we can use sample data similar way from **@tools:sample** in Preview Composable ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**`@PreviewParameter`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/tooling/preview/PreviewParameter).

For example:

```
data class Obj(val name :String,val count:Int)

@Composable
fun ObjCard(obj:Obj) {
    Card(
        Modifier.width(100.dp).height(50.dp)){
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        {
            Text("Name = " +obj.name)
            Text("Count = " +obj.count)
        }
    }
}
```

In this case you can implement the `PreviewParameterProvider` interface and create something like:

```
class SampleObjProvider: PreviewParameterProvider<Obj> {
    override val values = sequenceOf(
         Obj("Obj1",10),
         Obj("Obj2",70))
    override val count: Int = values.count()
}
```

Finally apply the `@PreviewParameter` to the `ObjCard` composable:

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ObjCard(@PreviewParameter(SampleObjProvider::class)  obj:Obj) {
    //..same code 
}
```

[image]