# How to pass data class values to @PreviewParameter annotation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to get a preview of a composable **which takes one data class as input and another one is the clickable listener**. I am not sure how the `@PreviewParameter` annotation is supposed to be used.

Preview error:

> Composable functions with non-default parameters are not supported in Preview unless they are annotated with @PreviewParameter.

**Data class**

```
data class MaterialData(
    var title:String,
    var description:String,
    var image: Int = R.drawable.m3_red_banner_mini,
    var textColor:String,
    var ref:String)
```

**Main activity sample calling fun:**

```
CardViewWidget(
    MaterialData(
        "All buttons",
        "When choosing the right button for an action, consider the level of emphasis inherent to a button type.",
         R.drawable.m3_red_banner_mini,
        "FFFFFF",
        "https://m3.material.io/components/cards/implementation/android") ,
    onClick = {


})
```

**Called fun**

```
package com.materialize.compose.util

import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.Card
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.SpanStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.buildAnnotatedString
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.withStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.materialize.compose.model.MaterialData

@Preview
@Composable
fun CardViewWidget( @PreviewParameter() mdcData: MaterialData, onClick:()-> Unit) {
    // start card view
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(15.dp)
            .clickable(onClick = onClick),
        shape =  RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
        elevation = 10.dp
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                buildAnnotatedString {
                    append("welcome to ")
                    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.W900, color = Color(0xFF4552B8))
                    ) {
                        append("Jetpack Compose Playground")
                    }
                }
            )
            Text(
                buildAnnotatedString {
                    append("Now you are in the ")
                    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.W900)) {
                        append("Card")
                    }
                    append(" section")
                }
            )
        }
    }
    // end card view
}
```

[image]

**Tried the below answer: still, i got some error**

```
package com.materialize.compose.util

import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.Card
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.SpanStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.buildAnnotatedString
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.withStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewParameter
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewParameterProvider
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.materialize.compose.R
import com.materialize.compose.model.MaterialData

class SampleObjProvider: PreviewParameterProvider<MaterialData> {
    override val values = sequenceOf(
        MaterialData(
            "All buttons 1",
            "When choosing the right button for an action, consider the level of emphasis inherent to a button type.",
            R.drawable.m3_red_banner_mini,
            "FFFFFF",
            "https://m3.material.io/components/cards/implementation/android"),
        MaterialData(
            "All buttons 2",
            "When choosing the right button for an action, consider the level of emphasis inherent to a button type.",
            R.drawable.m3_red_banner_mini,
            "FFFFFF",
            "https://m3.material.io/components/cards/implementation/android"))
    override val count: Int = values.count()
}


@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun CardViewWidget(@PreviewParameter(SampleObjProvider::class) mdcData: MaterialData,
                   onClick:()-> Unit) {
    // start card view
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(15.dp)
            .clickable(onClick = onClick),
        shape =  RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
        elevation = 10.dp
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                buildAnnotatedString {
                    append("welcome to ")
                    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.W900, color = Color(0xFF4552B8))
                    ) {
                        append("Jetpack Compose Playground")
                    }
                }
            )
            Text(
                buildAnnotatedString {
                    append("Now you are in the ")
                    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.W900)) {
                        append("Card")
                    }
                    append(" section")
                }
            )
        }
    }
    // end card view
}
```

[image]

**Error is:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.materialize.compose.util.CardViewKt.CardViewWidget, parameter onClick
    at com.materialize.compose.util.CardViewKt.CardViewWidget(CardView.kt)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.CommonPreviewUtils.invokeComposableMethod(CommonPreviewUtils.kt:149)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.CommonPreviewUtils.invokeComposableViaReflection$ui_tooling_release(CommonPreviewUtils.kt:188)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:571)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:569)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:608)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:564)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.InspectableKt.Inspectable(Inspectable.kt:64)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:513)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:512)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:508)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.access$WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:121)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:564)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:561)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:384)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:227)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:150)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:113)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:106)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:162)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3332)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2577)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2566)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotState.kt:540)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2566)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2517)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:477)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:727)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:433)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:727)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:187)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:142)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:814)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20479)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3489)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:44)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:360)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:714)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:870)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use sample data in Composable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67142449/how-to-use-sample-data-in-composable)

Comment: I tried these links without onclick operation working, but if i try to pass on click listener java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null (render not working)

Comment: You need to create a composable function `CardViewWidgetPreview`, and call `CardViewWidget` with needed parameters from it. Preview function cannot have non `@PreviewParameter` parameters, as in your case `onClick` does